# Fitting a curve to a drawing in Gimp

Tags: gimp

I'd like to make a logo which contains some mathematically defined shapes (to wit, a log-normal and normal distribution; see below). I can generate an image of these shapes using Python's Matplotlib, but I would like to import this into Gimp.

In Gimp, I'm aware of the tool for drawing Bezier curves by hand, as well as the 'select by color' option which could be used to select the curves. However, I'd like the lines to be a constant thickness. Is there a way to 'fit' two constant-thickness lines to a picture like this in Gimp?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have them as Paths (in other words, Bezier curves) just "stroke" them (*Edit>Stroke path* if done manually, `pdb.gimp_edit_stroke_vectors(layer,path)` in Python).